# Select rows where ID is repeated, but value in another column is different

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

[image: FRUIT TABLE]

What I would like to be able to do is return the IDs and how many different types of fruit the ID is associated with other than 1 like so:

[image: OUTPUT]

Can someone help me out? I don't think it should be that difficult, but I haven't had much luck.

Thanks!

Comment: `COUNT()` and `GROUP BY ID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the `having` clause and `count(distinct)`:

```
select id, count(distinct fruit) as numfruit
from t
group by id
having count(distinct fruit) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
select id, count (id)
from yourtable
group by id;
```

**[Demo](http://rextester.com/TBWN49634)**

Comment: Hi, This is close to what Im looking for but not quite it. 

I want it to return the ID and the number of distinct fruits. For example, in my table ID 1 had two distinct fruits, ID 2 had 1 distinct fruit, and ID 3 had 3 distrinct fruits.

Thanks!

Comment: @alfredoalegria the desired outputs does not show that.